# Escrever em caixa de texto no IE usando VBA

Tags: vba

Olá,

1ª duvida: O VBA consegue se comunicar com HTML5? Tentei fazer o VBA clicar nos "botões" de uma pagina programada em HTML5 usando os métodos .Document.GetElementsByID, .Document.GetElementsByName, .Document.GetElementsByNameClass e .Document.GetElementsByTagName mas não deu certo. Não tem como por conta do HTML5 ser mais recente que a ultima atualização do VBA ou tem mas por outro método?

2ª Dúvida: A partir da segunda vez que eu rodo o código, o site que eu estou manipulando pelo VBA já está logado (mesmo eu não tendo clicado na opção de gravar dados). Isso faz com que o VBA apresente um erro, já que ele está tentando preencher o login e senha na tela seguinte à de login. 
Como faço para evitar que esse erro ocorra? Tem alguma forma de fazer o VBA rodar sempre como se fosse a primeira vez ou então fazer ele reconhecer que essa etapa já foi pulada e seguir para a seguinte?

Comment: Em tese sim, até pq ele seleciona a partir do seletor, no caso do ` .Document.GetElementsByID` ele recupera pelo id do elemento...

Comment: Olá. Poderia mostrar o código existente? Poderia ser bastante útil à resolução da questão.